# Как сделать  OBJECT ссылочным?

Tags: html

Всем привет! Народ, помогите разобраться. На сайте имеется flash баннер, необходимо сделать его ссылочным, перепробовал всё, что знал, описываю варианты которые испробовал:

**1ый вариант** (атрибут onclick прописан самому элементу OBJECT) - не отрабатывает, редирект не происходит:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://test.ru/banner.swf" height="150" width="200" onclick="'window.location = "http://ya.ru";'">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://test.ru/banner.swf" />
</object>
```

**2ой вариант** (сделал DIV-обертку для элемента OBJECT) - не отрабатывает, редирект не происходит::

```
<div onclick="redirectionLink();" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://test.ru/banner.swf" height="150" width="200" onclick="'window.location = "http://ya.ru";'">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://test.ru/banner.swf" />
</object>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectionLink() {
        window.location = "http://ya.ru";
    }
</script>
```

**3ий вариант** (создал блок DIV и расположил его поверх элемента OBJECT, событие onclick прописал DIV`у) - работает только в Crhome, в остальных браузерах мой DIV находится под элементом OBJECT:

```
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; z-index: 99999; top: -150px;" onclick="redirectionLink();">
    </div>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://test.ru/banner.swf" height="150" width="200" onclick="'window.location = "http://ya.ru";'">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://test.ru/banner.swf" />
    </object>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectionLink() {
        window.location = "http://ya.ru";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. флеш публиковать с параметром `wmode=transparent` — это позволит div-контейнеру принимать JS-события над флешем;
2. ловить не `onclick`, а `onmousedown`, это в большем числе браузеров сработает.

Примерно так:

```
<div onmousedown="clickBanner(1)">
  <object>
    <param name="movie" value="3.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="3.swf"></embed>
  </object>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object).

Comment: Благодарю добрый человек! Действительно все заработало :)